# Loading Variable-Based Parameters in Behavior Search

Tags: netlogo, behaviorsearch

I am using [Behavior Search](http://behaviorsearch.org) to calibrate my NetLogo model for 20 different hospital units. I am using global variables to set the min and max for several sliders in my model, but I think this is causing an error in Behavior Search when I attempt to load the parameter values from the model. However, I don't want to manually enter these parameter ranges manually each time I use Behavior Search.

Is there a way to get around this error? Is there a way to set the min and max for a specific slider to a constant, rather than using global variables?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BehaviorSearch developer here -- if I'm understanding your question correctly, your NetLogo model has a slider which has a min/max constraint that is not set to a constant, but is instead set to a global variable (in the slider settings, accessed from the NetLogo interface).

When I choose such a model using the BehaviorSearch GUI, and then click the "Load parameter ranges from model interface" button, then I get the value of 0 for that constraint. (I don't see any error message -- just the value 0 (if you're getting an error message instead, then I may not be understanding your situation correctly, and perhaps you could post exactly what error message you're seeing?)

This will be true *even* if you are setting the slider min/max to a global value in the special STARTUP procedure (see: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/startup.html), because STARTUP is only run when a model loads in the NetLogo GUI, and not when a model is loaded in headless NetLogo.

Thus, unfortunately, I think the answer to your question is: "no, there isn't a way to get BehaviorSearch to load the parameter ranges from global variables within the model".

Some possible work-arounds:

1. BehaviorSearch is open-source -- some changes could be made to it -- i.e., maybe adding in a call to "startup" whenever BehaviorSearch GUI loads the parameter ranges would be sufficient for you.
2. If you're only doing a few searches, I don't see why manually editing the parameter ranges would be particularly onerous.  However, if you're generating a lot of different searches with this model, then I can see how it might be an issue.  The .bsearch files are just XML text files, so you might consider generating them without the BehaviorSearch GUI, e.g. using a scripting language.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions!! To clarify, yes, I am getting 0 for the min and max constraints. Originally, I was getting an illegal number format error, but I discovered that this was caused by another issue in my model.

For now, I will work with manually entering the parameter ranges, and just running searches based on 20 'template' .bsearch files (one for each hospital, and actually for two different time periods). I will explore your suggestions if I need to develop even more search files. Thanks!!